# Add columns to data frame to calculate log return

Tags: r

I have a data frame with time series financial data, and I want to calculate the log returns for each of them.

Here is a simplified example (In reality, I have hundereds of columns):

`df <- data.frame(Date=c("2004/10/29","2004/11/30","2004/12/31","2005/01/31"), B126 =c("103.238","104.821","105.141","107.682"), H251 =c("131.149","138.989","137.266","137.080"))
df`

```
        Date    B126    H251
1 2004/10/29 103.238 131.149
2 2004/11/30 104.821 138.989
3 2004/12/31 105.141 137.266
4 2005/01/31 107.682 137.080
```

I want to get the following:

```
        Date    B126     Log      H251     Log
1 2004/10/29 103.238           131.149 
2 2004/11/30 104.821  0.0152   138.989  0.0580
3 2004/12/31 105.141  0.0030   137.266 -0.0124
4 2005/01/31 107.682  0.0238   137.080 -0.0013
```

I know how to get log returns for each column by using:

`logB126 <- DF$B126
log_returns <- diff(log(logB126), lag = 1)`

It is impossible for me to repeat the above steps hundred times so I'm wondering if there is a better way to perform the task?

Comment: are trying to log every value in df$B126? why is the first row empty in your want?

Comment: @Nathan Day Log "0.0152", for example, =Log(104.821/103.238). Basically it's the log return for 11/2004 and that's why I wanted the first row empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `for` loop should do the job:

```
df2 <- df[,1:2]
for(name in names(df)[2:length(names(df))]){
    df2[,name] <- df[,name]
    df2[2:nrow(df2),paste0(name, ".Log")] <- diff(log(as.numeric(as.character(df[,name]))), lag = 1)
}
head(df2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `plyr::colwise`

```
calc_log_return <- function(x) diff(log(x), lag = 1)
logReturns <- plyr::colwise(calc_log_return)(DF[, -1])
```

This will make a new `data.frame` of just the log returns. You can easily append the dates column.

Comment: Thank you! But I get this error message `Error in Math.factor(x) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors` after running `logReturns <- plyr::colwise(calc_log_return)(DF[, -1])`

Comment: have you checked that all your columns are numeric? Use `str`. Only takes one column with some text in it to mess up

Comment: I was running the code on my sample data. `str(df)` returns `'data.frame':4 obs. of  3 variables` Is the `Date` column causing the problem?

Comment: No - the DF[, -1] removes the date column. The problem is the quotes in the sample data. They force the columns to be character vectors, which are then automatically converted to factors. Remove these and everything will work.

Comment: I'm very new to R. Can you please be more specific about the "quotes" and how to remove them? I appreciate your help!

Comment: You have `B126 =c("103.238","104.821","105.141","107.682")`, just change it to `B126 =c(103.238,104.821,105.141,107.682)`. etc

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mutate_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_each(funs(round(c(NA, diff(log(as.numeric(as.character(.))))),3)),
                                     B126:H251)
#        Date  B126   H251
#1 2004/10/29    NA     NA
#2 2004/11/30 0.015  0.058
#3 2004/12/31 0.003 -0.012
#4  2005/0131 0.024 -0.001
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dplyr solution.  After applying mutate_each, use merge from base R to add the new columns to the original data.

```
library(dplyr)

# clean up data (convert strings to numbers)
df <- df %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))), B126:H251)

# calculate log diff and merge
df %>% merge(df %>% mutate_each(funs(c(NA,diff(log(.)))), B126:H251), by='Date', suffixes=c('','_log'))

# optionally apply rounding function
df %>% mutate_each(funs(round(.,3)), B126_log:H251_log)
```

Output:

```
        Date    B126    H251 B126_log H251_log
1 2004/10/29 103.238 131.149       NA       NA
2 2004/11/30 104.821 138.989    0.015    0.058
3 2004/12/31 105.141 137.266    0.003   -0.012
4  2005/0131 107.682 137.080    0.024   -0.001
```